# Finding records that do not have any or no correct "child" record

Tags: soql

I'm working in a Salesforce-based solution with customizations in place. One table (let's call it `RRTracker__c` for the purposes of this question) contains requests and their responses. Let's assume that its records can either be of type `Request` or of `Response`. One request can have multiple responses.

The `Request` has a relationship `Responses__r` pointing to the responses. A `Response` has the field `Parent_Request__c` pointing to the original `Request`. Also, the response has a few fields that characterize it as "valid" for the purposes of this question.

To simplify the real scenario, let's just assume that "valid" could be expressed as a simple field value `'Yes'` in the field `Valid__c`.

---

Using SOQL (via an REST API request to the Salesforce platform), I need to find requests that do not have valid responses.

One approach to start would be this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Responses__r WHERE Valid__c != 'Yes')
FROM RRTracker__c
WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Request'
```

This will list *all* `Request`s and will provide a list of valid `Response`s for each `Request`. I could run this query and implement something that consumes this output to filter for `Request`s that have no valid `Respose`.

However, as there are hundred-thousands of records in this table, this solution will not work: The load & download effort would be way too huge.

---

Therefore I'm looking for solution that goes somewhat like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Responses__r WHERE Valid__c != 'Yes') AS subquery
FROM RRTracker__c
WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Request'
AND subquery.totalCount = 0
```

Because this would use the `AS` statement, this is no valid SOQL query.

--> How can I filter for the count of records in a subquery using SOQL?

Answer (score 1):

`SOQL`, doesnt allow you to filtering based on the count of records in a subquery  like your normal SQL does, but we can do it using `SOQL` in 2 steps

```
// Step 1: Get all the IDs of Requests with Valid Responses
SELECT Parent_Request__c FROM RRTracker__c WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Response' AND Valid__c = 'Yes'

// Step 2: Get all the Requests that are not in the above list
SELECT Id, Name FROM RRTracker__c WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Request' AND Id NOT IN :[Set of IDs from step 1]
```